# Creating custom Object classes android

Tags: android, class, data-structures, android-sharedpreferences

In my app, I want to store certain data, using a custom object.

The data I want to save is: http://prntscr.com/ip1jyp (Ignore the fact it's in Firebase. Just used that to show you the structure)

The above is the workouts a user has created (Defined by "Workout 1", "Workout 2" etc...)

Inside each workout contains the following:
- Workout Name
- Workout Colour
- Workout Activities

A user adds an activity (as defined by "1", "2", "3" etc...) which contains the following:
- Activity Name
- Activity Time

My question is how would I go about creating a custom workout class that can contain this information and retrieve it when requested. Then, each user will have multiple workout classes. Note: The custom workout class will be stored in shared preferences.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for this:

```
class Workout() {
    int colour;
    String name;
    List<Activity> activities;
}

class Activity() {
    String name;
    int time;
}
```

And to store them on shared-prefs I would use JSON (parse object to Json strings)

Comment: Yeah, I just had a little experiment myself and that's exactly what I got. At least I've got clarification on how to do it and if my thoughts were efficient. Thanks :)